# How does memset work

Tags: c++

I have created a macro     `#define ll long long int` just to avoid the pain of typing.

Now I have some code like this.

```
ll size = 2;
ll *arr = new ll[size];
memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
```

When I tried to run this.

I see the values of arr as **4294967296 420906795007** instead of **0 0**

How does memset work?

Comment: Nothing to do with `memset()`, `sizeof(arr)` gives you the size of the pointer variable, not `size`.

Comment: Since you're supposedly using C++ why are you even trying to use the C library's `memset` function for this ? Use value initialisation or `std::fill` and write proper idiomatic C++, not "C masquerading as C++".

Comment: why use a macro for `long long int` instead of a `typedef` or `alias`?

Comment: @RyanP -- That macro seems to be part of the horrible coding standards that "online judge" posts use.  Do a search and you'll see tons of posts with that very same macro, all SPOJ and "online judge" posts.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is you use wrong size in memset call:

```
 memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`arr` is a pointer so `sizeof(arr)` is equal to 8 on 64-bit machine and 4 on 32-bit, what you want is:

```
memset(arr,0,sizeof(ll) * size);
```

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof(arr)` will give the size of a pointer, not the allocated memory.

Try this to calculate the size to zero-clear:

```
ll size = 2;
ll *arr = new ll[size];
memset(arr,0,sizeof(*arr) * size);
```